# Java visualization library called "C-BOMB" or something? I think I misheard

Tags: java, visualization

I was talking to a Java coder yesterday, and they mentioned that they used a visualization library to make some interesting graphics (pie charts, a gui, bar charts perhaps).

It was called something like "c-bomb" or "see bon". They had a thick french accent and the phone line was bad.

Any ideas what it could refer to?

Comment: Contact the original person again to ask?

Answer (score 1):

Could be s/he was simply saying "it is good" (*c'est bien*).

Comment: This would be my guess, or some variation. Maybe it was d3.js, which would match the description (it's very good) and also be hard to notice as a name in the flow of conversation.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound anything near what you mention I know, but [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) is what comes to my mind, when it comes to Java and chart generation/visualization.